# How to add a widget from the mac_widgets java api to HudWindow

Tags: java, jpanel, widget, macos, hud

Good day,

I recently came accross the [mac_widgets api for java](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/). I went through the docementation and exaples but i didn't find a way to add widgets to the HudWindow. I came accross an online solution

> panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout?(panel, BoxLayout?.Y_AXIS));
>   panel.add(sourceList.getComponent());

This works if panel is a reference to a JPanel object and it is add to a JFrame window.

Is there a way i can add panel to the HudWindow in the mac_widgets api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, of course you wont get the transparency. But this is how you add a panel to a HUD window. Try extracting the MacWiget.jar file to view other classes. The components have different names, in this case a panel is called ActivePanel.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

import com.explodingpixels.macwidgets.ActivePanel;
import com.explodingpixels.macwidgets.HudWidgetFactory;
import com.explodingpixels.macwidgets.HudWindow;

public class MacWidgetTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setGUI();   
    }

    public static void setGUI() {
        System.out.println("Starting GUI");
        HudWindow hud = new HudWindow("Window");
        hud.getJDialog().setSize(300, 350);
        hud.getJDialog().setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ActivePanel panel = new ActivePanel();
        JButton button = HudWidgetFactory.createHudButton("Button");
        panel.add(button);
        hud.setContentPane(panel);
        hud.getJDialog().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```